# I want to strip certain characters from a textarea - PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

---

### The Details

---

I have a simple textarea `<textarea></textarea>`

The value of this textarea is sent through ajax and stored in a database.

The value in this database is viewed on an iPad (or iPad mini or iPhone, etc)

---

### The Problem

---

When someone copies text from somewhere (could be anywhere from the internet potentially), I want to remove any weird characters such as: `“windows-1252 quotes”` from the text before storing them in a `utf8_unicode_ci` column in a database.  This column stores the above quotes but are unknown on certain devices (like iPad)

---

### The Question

---

How can I remove these characters in `Javascript` or `PHP`?

`string.replace` has been tried from various examples to remove these characters.

`htmlentities($sample)` has been tried in order to convert these characters but still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your current code and explain explicitly what is not working?

Comment: If you are working with a mysql database, you might want to take a look at the php function mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will do this; php's function for this is `preg_replace`, javascript's is simply `.replace()`. You can find usage snippets everywhere ;)

There are two ways to approach this using regex:

**1. Define an allowed character range and strip anything that isn't in that range.**

`[^\w-=+()!@#$%^*(]` will match NOT anything in this character range (the `^` at the beginning of the character class denotes this). You can then take the resulting matched characters and replace with an empty string.

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/zK2qW6

**2. Define a non-allowed character range and strip anything that is in that range.**

`[“”]` will match anything in this character range. You can then take the resulting matched characters, and again replace with an empty string. You could also use a regex [unicode range](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) here too.

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/yG4qJ4

---

In the end, you should choose the path which requires the smallest expression. If there's only a handful of characters to replace, use option #2. If you only want to allow a handful of characters, use option #1.